What adapters should I use with my s19 and a dryer outlet?
I'm just getting into crypto mining and was wondering what adapters I should use. I see a lot of people using PDUs but I'm not sure if that's necessary here because I only have the one s19. I am using a 240V 30A American plug, so if anyone can help that would be great! thanks.
